# htaccess goes to a folder when it's not supposed to

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my htaccess files.
Here is my folder structure:

```
 - /scripts/ - common php scripts 
 - /static/ - static file - mainly photos
        /photos/ - image files
        /.htaccess  - *static htaccess* if there is no photos's dimentions - create one
 - /photos/ - photos subdomain
        /.htaccess - *photos htaccess* handling slim for that subdomain
 - /www/ - www subdomain
 - /.htaccess  - *main htaccess* separation of subdomains
```

My problem is that when I call `http://static.domain.local/photos/my-photo.jpg`, the request first goes to *photos htaccess* and then to *photos htaccess* with changed path for 404 error since requested file is not in `/photos/` folder. It should go to `/static/photos/` and find (or not) this file.
I always get wrong script executed.

Here are my htacces files:

**main htaccess**

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.(local|pl)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ www/public%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^photos.domain.(local|pl)$
RewriteRule ^ photos%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.domain.(local|pl)$
RewriteRule ^ static%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

**static htaccess**

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /generate.php
```

**photos htaccess**

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```